# Stepping through code using PhantomJS while running tests using Karma

Tags: javascript, phantomjs, karma-runner

I am running my tests using Karma on PhantomJS, and am facing an asynchronous run loop issue. I was wondering if there is anyway to interactively debug code(step through) when tests are running.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: There may be better ways, but I would just step through with your browser's dev tools. Set a breakpoint in chrome, or use a `debugger;` statement.

Comment: I would do that, but the problem is that I am facing a issue specifically on PhantomJS. The tests run just fine on chrome and firefox.

Comment: What Nick means is that there is a remote debugger in plain phantomjs and you can set breakpoints with `debugger;`.

Comment: I see. Do I need to specifically enable this remote debugger. I would really appreciate it if you could please point me to some documentation for the same.

Comment: Specifically how to start phantomJS with debugger, while using Karma

Answer (score 3):

If you are using [karma-phantomjs-launcher](https://www.npmjs.com/package/karma-phantomjs-launcher) npm package in your karma tests, you can add the following snippet in the `karma.conf.js` file to run PhantomJS in debugger mode:

```
browsers: ['PhantomJS_custom'],

// you can define custom flags
customLaunchers: {
  'PhantomJS_custom': {
    base: 'PhantomJS',
    debug: true
  }
}
```

After this, write a `debugger;` statement where you want to place the breakpoint in your code.

Now, when you start the karma test runner, you will see that PhantomJS is waiting for your browser to connect to the debugger port to start execution of tests.

```
29 12 2016 13:14:25.269:INFO [launcher]: Starting browser PhantomJS
29 12 2016 13:14:25.325:INFO [phantomjs.launcher]: ACTION REQUIRED:
29 12 2016 13:14:25.325:INFO [phantomjs.launcher]: 
29 12 2016 13:14:25.326:INFO [phantomjs.launcher]:   Launch browser at
29 12 2016 13:14:25.326:INFO [phantomjs.launcher]:   http://localhost:9000/webkit/inspector/inspector.html?page=2
29 12 2016 13:14:25.326:INFO [phantomjs.launcher]: 
29 12 2016 13:14:25.326:INFO [phantomjs.launcher]: Waiting 15 seconds ...
```

Point your chrome to the address specified in the logs.  Now, you will see a debugger interface served from Phantomjs.  The code executes in PhantomJS engine but you can observe breakpoints, evaluate expressions  and perform many debugging operations from any webkit based browser.

Answer (score 1):

You can set `debugger` statement within one of your test blocks. And then point your browser to whatever url you are running karma at and open your dev tools. The debugger should fire whenever it reaches your test block.

Assuming jasmine/mocha with expect:

```
it('fires a debugger', function () {
  var bool = true || false;
  debugger;

  while(bool) {
    // uh oh...
  }
});
```

In my experience, the debugger will fire on both `http://localhost:<your-karma-port>` and `http://localhost:<your-karma-port>/debug.html`, but you may have more luck using the debug url.

If you aren't able to see your debugger statements, there may be a bigger issue with your testing setup.